# Capturing Image doesn't display

Tags: android, android-image

I have a button that should let me take or choose 4 pictures and display each in their respective ImageViews instantly. This means I could choose to take the first picture, choose the second, choose the third and take the fourth; etc..

My code works so that the four `URI`s are stored in an `ArrayList` and pulled from there for display. Weirdly, only the pictures I chose from gallery show up. i.e. I chose my first picture from gallery and took the other three pictures; only the first displays. I have debugged and I am successfully getting a `URI` back from "taken" pictures. What's more, these pictures are also found in my gallery.

Please take a look at my code and see where I go wrong.

`takePictureIntent()`:

```
private void dispatchTakePictureIntent() {
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
            // Create the File where the photo should go
            File photoFile = null;
            try {
                photoFile = createImageFile();
                outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(photoFile);
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Log.w("error","IOException");
            }catch (NullPointerException nullEx) {
                Log.w("error","NullPointerException");
            }
            // Camera.
            final List<Intent> cameraIntents = new ArrayList<Intent>();
            final Intent captureIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            final PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();
            final List<ResolveInfo> listCam = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(captureIntent, 0);
            for (ResolveInfo res : listCam) {
                final String packageName = res.activityInfo.packageName;
                final Intent intent = new Intent(captureIntent);
                intent.setComponent(new ComponentName(res.activityInfo.packageName, res.activityInfo.name));
                intent.setPackage(packageName);
                intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(photoFile));
                cameraIntents.add(intent);
            }
            // Filesystem.
            final Intent galleryIntent = new Intent();
            galleryIntent.setType("image/*");
            galleryIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
            // Chooser of filesystem options.
            final Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(galleryIntent, "Select Source");
            // Add the camera options.
            chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, cameraIntents.toArray(new Parcelable[cameraIntents.size()]));
            if(id.equals(HAPPY_ID))
                startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, REQUEST_HAPPY_PHOTO);
            if(id.equals(SURPRISED_ID))
                startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, REQUEST_SURPRISED_PHOTO);
            if(id.equals(AFRAID_ID))
                startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, REQUEST_AFRAID_PHOTO);
            if(id.equals(UPSET_ID))
                startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, REQUEST_UPSET_PHOTO);
            if(id.equals(SAD_ID))
                startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, REQUEST_SAD_PHOTO);
        }
    }
}
```

`onActivityResult()`:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            if (requestCode == REQUEST_HAPPY_PHOTO || requestCode == REQUEST_SURPRISED_PHOTO || requestCode == REQUEST_AFRAID_PHOTO ||
                    requestCode == REQUEST_UPSET_PHOTO || requestCode == REQUEST_SAD_PHOTO) {
                final boolean isCamera;
                if (data == null) {
                    isCamera = true;
                } else {
                    final String action = data.getAction();
                    if (action == null) {
                        isCamera = false;
                    } else {
                        isCamera = action.equals(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                    }
                }
                Uri selectedImageUri;
                if (isCamera) {
                    selectedImageUri = outputFileUri;
                } else {
                    selectedImageUri = data == null ? null : data.getData();
                }
                //Log.d("doing ids", "right before id");
                //Log.d("doing ids", "id is " + id);
                if(requestCode == REQUEST_HAPPY_PHOTO) {
                    //Log.d("doing ids", "in happy");
                    happyList.add(selectedImageUri);
                }
                if(requestCode == REQUEST_SURPRISED_PHOTO) {
                    //Log.d("doing ids", "in surprised");
                    surprisedList.add(selectedImageUri);
                }
                if(requestCode == REQUEST_AFRAID_PHOTO) {
                    //Log.d("doing ids", "in surprised");
                    afraidList.add(selectedImageUri);
                }
                if(requestCode == REQUEST_UPSET_PHOTO) {
                    //Log.d("doing ids", "in surprised");
                    upsetList.add(selectedImageUri);
                }
                if(requestCode == REQUEST_SAD_PHOTO) {
                    //Log.d("doing ids", "in surprised");
                    sadList.add(selectedImageUri);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: where id defined..

Comment: @mithatkonuk id is defined, it's a class variable. Sorry for not including it.